# Extremely hard sum of infinite series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this in a previous years iit paper. It seems really interesting, but incredibly difficult. Can someone please help

> $$
> \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \arctan\frac{1}{2i^2}
> $$
>
> This whole expression is equal to $t$
>
> Find $\tan(t)$